# New activity from intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-gallery

I have fragment with button with intent for Gallery

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        //если выбрали галерею
        case R.id.b_gallery:
            Intent intentGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intentGallery.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intentGallery, GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
        break;
```

Then I choose any photo and receive URI. I have to show chosen photo in new activity. In fragment i do:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturned) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturned);
    switch (requestCode) {

        //если результат пришел от галереи
           case GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturned.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent last_intent_gallery = new Intent(getView().getContext(), ViewPhoto.class);
                last_intent_gallery.putExtra("fotka", bitmap);
                startActivity(last_intent_gallery);
            }
            break;
```

In new activity i do:

```
public class ViewPhoto extends Activity {

    //public final static String THIEF = ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_photo_layout);

        CustomImageVIew imageView = (CustomImageVIew)findViewById(R.id.customImageVIew);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bitmap fotka = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("fotka");
        imageView.setBitmap(fotka);

    }
```

But after i choose photo Gallery just close and i again get my fragment.
Where is my decision?

My AndroidManifest has:

```
<activity android:name=".fragments.ViewPhoto"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: there is no error at the log ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua no, just close gallery

Comment: Does the control gets inside `onActivityResult` ?

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand your question. What a controls you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Request codes for your starting activity for result and getting result are not the same constant. See the names of the constants. One has "photo" in it. One has "gallery". Use same code for requesting and getting result.

Edit: 
I see your edit now based on your comment below. See if your call to onActivityResult is not intercepted by activity. It usually is. In that case in your activity forward the call to your fragment method. Or just override the method in activity so it implements the super. Which will call the fragment method. It's a common issue with starting activity for result with fragment. Do some logging. See if it calls the method in fragment. My guess is.. it doesn't.  That's why no action is taken.

Comment: It was mistake during doing post. I edited my code. Sorry

Comment: I see your edit now. See if your call to onActibityResult is not intercepted by activity. It usually is. In that case in your activity forward the call to your fragment method. Or just override the method in activity so it implements the super. Which will call the fragment method. It's a common issue with starting activity for result with fragment. Do some logging. See if it calls the method in fragment. My guess is.. it doesn't.  That's why no action is taken.

Comment: Oh, may i show to you some part of my code which will help you to help me? If it is what part i may show?

Comment: Your code is sufficient. I suggest using log statements to see of your method onActivityResult in fragment is called. What the result is... you will see with proper logging where the problem is. It could be your method is never called... or the result is not ok...

Comment: I'm still not understand what i have to change

Comment: Create log statements. F.e at the beginning of onActivityResult method create log which will print "onResult is called". Inside the condition create another log which says f.e. "result is ok". Add as many logs as you need to debug every step of the way. So you can find out what is not called. Or which condition is not working like you think.  Log statements are for you to debug.

Comment: Yes you are right. It seems RESUL NOT OKAY. But why?

Comment: RESULT_OK is a static integer. It's always 0. You need to check if your resultCode == RESULT_OK. and mainly check if your method is called at all. Why is it not ok?  May need more debugging. It should be OK since gallery returns with result.

Comment: If i understand right my activity can intercept method onActivityResult. What can be a reason of this? Context?

Comment: Yes it can. You can use that to your advantage. In this particular case it doesn't matter who handles your opening new activity, whether it's activity or fragment. You receive uri for image on result intent. You can start new activity from activity and not fragment. Or you can intercept the request code in activity and pass it to your fragment, by obtaining active fragment object, calling the method onActivityResult in that object, passing all the parameters. They are the same. But imo in your case if activity in fact intercepts, just start second activity from there.